# syntaxError: Invalid syntax when connecting to wallaroo

Tags: python

I was following this tutorial "https://blog.wallaroolabs.com/2017/11/identifying-trending-twitter-hashtags-in-real-time-with-wallaroo/" when I run `twitter_client.py` I get this error:

> File "twitter_client.py", line 44  print (connecting to Wallaroo on
>   %s:%s) % (wallaro_input_address) syntaxError: invalid systax.

this is the code

```
import socket
import sys
import requests
import requests_oauthlib
import json

# Replace the values below with yours
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
my_auth = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, 
CONSUMER_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
def send_tweets_to_wallaroo(http_resp, tcp_connection):
for line in http_resp.iter_lines():
try:
full_tweet = json.loads(line)
if 'text' in full_tweet:
tweet_text = full_tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
# send the length of text + 1 for newline represented as 5 ASCII
# characters, followed by the tweet text and \n
# e.g. if tweet text is 'Hello everyone!', send '00016Hello everyone!'
tcp_connection.sendall(str(len(tweet_text)+1).zfill(5) +
tweet_text + '\n')
except:
print ("Error decoding data received from Twitter!")
def get_tweets():
url = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json'
query_data = [('locations', '-130,-20,100,50'), ('track', '#')]
query_url = url + '?' + '&'.join([str(t[0]) + '=' + str(t[1]) for t in 
query_data])
response = requests.get(query_url, auth=my_auth, stream=True)
return response
# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to Wallaroo
wallaro_input_address = ('localhost', 8002)

print (connecting to Wallaroo on %s:%s) % (wallaro_input_address)
sock.connect(wallaro_input_address)

resp = get_tweets()
send_tweets_to_wallaroo(resp,sock)
```

please help... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line instead of the 44-th line:

`print('connecting to Wallaroo on %s:%s' % (wallaro_input_address))`

Another way of formatting in python3:

`print('connecting to Wallaroo on {}'.format(wallaro_input_address))`

Comment: thanks, I got it. but I also get this error connecting to Wallaroo on localhost:8002
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_client.py", line 45, in <module>
    sock.connect(wallaro_input_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the
 target machine actively refused it

Comment: Well, that simply means Wallaroo is not running on your localhost. Try searching and configure it in order to run it. Your client is working properly now and wants to connect to Wallaroo which is not listening on port 8002.